# Trimmed String Expand and Show Complete Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html, events

Here I am Trying to Display some Information on the Google Map Marker. The Description contains a long String of length somewhere around 500 characters which I Cut Short to 225 chars and then add a Link using anchor tag saying Show More.
 Now the Problem,
I want it to Expand the Marker and Show rest of the Information. How can I do this?

```
function stringTrimmer(text, flag) {
var textLength = text.length;
if (flag !== null && flag !== true) {

    if (text.length > 225) {
        var text1 = text.substring(0, 224) + "..." + "<a href=#>Show More </a>";
        return text1;
    }
} else if (flag === true) {
    return text;
}};
```

Which is not working. Can Someone Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code and edit it to suit your needs

```
function stringTrimmer(text, flag) {
var textLength = text.length;
if (flag !== null && flag !== true) {

    if (text.length > 225) {
        var text1 = text.substring(0, 224) + "..." + "<a class='show-more' old_val='"+text+"' href=#>Show More </a>";
        return text1;
    }
} else if (flag === true) {
    return text;
}};

$('.show-more').bind('click'){
$('some-element').html($(this).attr('old_val'))
}
```